# How do I include &, <, > etc in XML attribute values

Tags: java, xml, entityreference, xml-attribute

I want to create an XML file which will be used to store the structure of a Java program. I am able to successfully parse the Java program and create the tags as required. The problem arises when I try to include the source code inside my tags, since Java source code may use a vast number of entity reference and reserved characters like `&`, `<` ,`>` , `&`. I am not able to create a valid XML.

My XML should go like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<prg name="prg_name">
  <class name= "class_name>
    <parent>parent class</parent>
      <interface>Interface name</interface>
.
.
.
      <method name= "method_name">
        <statement>the ordinary java statement</statement>
        <if condition="Conditional Expression">
          <statement> true statements </statement>
        </if>
        <else>
          <statement> false statements </statement>
        </else>
        <statement> usual control statements </statement>
 .
 .
 .
      </method>
    </class>
 .
 .
 .
 </prg>
```

Like this, but the problem is conditional expressions of `if` or other statements have a lot of `&` or other reserved symbols in them which prevents XML from getting validated. Since all this data (source code) is given by the user I have little control over it. Escaping the characters will be very costly in terms of time.

I can use CDATA to escape the element text but it can not be used for attribute values containing conditional expressions. I am using [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) Java grammar to parse the Java program and getting the attributes and content for the tags. So is there any other workaround for it?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You will have to escape

```
" to  &quot;
' to  &apos;
< to  &lt;
> to  &gt;
& to  &amp;
```

for xml.

Comment: How about a + (plus)

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk "+" is okay to go as it is, don't need to escape it in XML. Maybe you were talking about URL escape?

Answer (score 37):

In XML attributes you must escape

```
" with &quot;
< with &lt;
& with &amp;
```

if you wrap attribute values in double quotes (`"`), e.g.

```
<MyTag attr="If a&lt;b &amp; b&lt;c then a&lt;c, it's obvious"/>
```

meaning tag `MyTag` with attribute `attr` with text `If a<b & b<c then a<c, it's obvious` - note: no need to use `&apos;` to escape `'` character.

If you wrap attribute values in single quotes (`'`) then you should escape these characters:

```
' with &apos;
< with &lt;
& with &amp;
```

and you can write `"` as is.
Escaping of `>` with `&gt;` in attribute text *is not required*, e.g. `<a b=">"/>` is well-formed XML.

Comment: Why does XML require that special characters inside the quotes be escaped in case of attribute values? Only " or ' would need to be quoted... and anything else inside that string could simply be considered as content!

Comment: I guess it's a pre-caution against badly written XML parsers and / or incorrect XML. For example, if quotes for attributes are omitted (`<tag attr=value></tag>`).

Comment: Not an expert but I would suspect this is an historical precaution due to SGML that was originally used to define HTML and other type markup langue.

Comment: Even with modern parsers, the closing tag is the problem. Starting tag doesn't give any error.

Comment: This is more correct than the accepted answer because it provides the minimal set of necessary escapes.

Comment: @Sorter That's a weird parser you have there then. According to the specification only `<` needs to be escaped: `AttValue ::= '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"` -- XML 1.0 (Fifth Edition). That said this is a case in point for favouring caution.