# MSBuild Exec command always fails

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to execute this simple command from MSBuild (VS2015, from a `.target` file) to generate the date of the current git commit:

```
git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:%d.%m.%Y
```

So in MSBuild I have tried:

```
<Exec Command="git show -s --format=%25cd --date=format:%25d.%25m.%25Y"  ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="BuildDate" />
</Exec>
```

But it yields only an error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: example, Configuration: Release Dll Win32 ------
1>  fatal: invalid --pretty format: d.Y
1>D:\example\gitversion.targets(26,5): error MSB3073: The command "git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:%d.%m.%Y" exited with code 128.
```

If I post the command within the quotation marks to the console, it works like a charm and prints `19.12.2016`.

I have tried the following things:

- Escape also the `=` sign, `:`, ... still does not work
- Use only `Command="git show -s --format=%25ci"` -> yields also an error `fatal: invalid --pretty format: ci` but works fine in console.
- surround with quotes `&quot;--format=%25ci&quot;` -> same error
- Call with `Command="git --version"`, this works as expected and returns the git version (same as on console)

I suspect that it somehow does not accept the `=` to specify the argument, but git won't let me pass it as separate arguments, e.g. separated by a space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `%25` to escape `%`, so your command becomes

```
<Exec Command="git show -s --format=%25%25cd --date=format:%25%25d.%25%25m.%25%25Y" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="BuildDate" />
</Exec>
```

See here for [MSBuild escape characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx)

Comment: It still does not really make sense to me, why I  need to escape it twice, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer helped me, but I had a slightly more complex scenario. Here's my own solution, with some added explanation:

```xml
<Exec Command="git log -1 --oneline --pretty=&quot;%25%25h %25%25ad &lt;%25%25ae&gt;&quot; &gt; $(OutputPath)/git-info.txt" />
```

This will execute this command:

```
git log -1 --oneline --pretty='%h %ad <%ae>' > bin/debug/git-info.txt
```

Here's what I understood of why each escape is needed:

- `%25` is the [MSBuild Special Characters escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a `%` sign
- `%25%25` then will create two percent signs which is the [cmd escape for percent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552702/419956)
- `&quot;` is the [xml attribute value escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709245/419956) for double quotes
- `&gt;` is the [xml attribute value escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709245/419956) for the `>` character