# Configuring mysql url in java

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, hibernate

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection property 'autoReconnect' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true;connectTimeout=360000;socketTimeout=360000' is not in this set.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a special character in XML and needs to be escaped as `&amp;`. Try the following configuration:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?autoReconnect=true&amp;connectTimeout=360000&amp;socketTimeout=360000" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="mysql" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>
```

See [How do I include &, <, > etc in XML attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709232/how-do-i-include-etc-in-xml-attribute-values).