# ResourceDictionary can't print '<'

Tags: c#

```
<sys:String x:Key="INVESTIGATE_FURTHER">weight<123</sys:String>
```

like that, it prints 'XML is not valid'.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the `weight<123` sequence. Perhaps you should instead replace the `<` with `&lt`;.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709245/1328968

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how you generate/save the ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The part:

`weight<123` contains a character `<` with special meaning in XML

You can escape it as:

`weight&lt;123`

`&gt; means '>'`