# How to prevent LXML from writing &amp; instead of just &?

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

I'm aware of the fact that the proper XML encoding for '&' is & but there is an attribute in the XML documents I work with that needs to remain '&' and not be converted to &.

In particular I need the HTML symbols for characters ' and " to be written as HTML symbols because they have to be properly rendered in the browser in some searches involving the XML docs.

When I do      el.set('lemma', '&#34;') or      el.set('lemma', '&#39;'), however, the resulting document has:

```
lemma="&amp;#34;"
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How about just `el.set('lemma', '&')`? would translate to `lemma="&amp;"` which would the the correct encoding,

Comment: Thanks once again @LMC. No, the value for the lemma attribute must be the complete HTML symbol for the apostrophe (') or the double quote ("), that is, either lemma="&#39;" or lemma="&#34;". Now I get lemma="&amp;#39;" and lemma="&amp;#34;"

Comment: Looks like it's not necessesary to escape the apóstrophe in attribute values https://stackoverflow.com/a/32588697/2834978

Comment: That is so with the apostrophe. But my problem is the amperstand '&'. 
So, I don't need to write an apostrophe on the XML document. The desired output is  lemma="&amp;#34;" . Whether I use  el.set('lemma', '&#34;'), i.e. single quotes or el.set('lemma', "&#34;") I always get lemma="&amp;#34;".  

If I escape the amperstand by doing el.set('lemma', '&amp;#34;'), then I get lemma="&amp;amp;#34;".   That is, LXML always translates '&' into '&amp;' because that is the XML symbol for the '&' character. But that's what I'm trying to avoid. Perhaps there is no way of doing it?

Comment: Seems you are trying to solve a view issue at data level. XML must be well formed so `&amp;` is the correct encoding, view layer should deal with the representation.

Comment: Thanks @LMC. The problem is that I have no control over the view layer. I have to submit the documents in the form that is requested and that is the form. I can do a simple search and replace and substitute  "&#34;" for "&amp;#34;" but I was hoping for a simpler solution. Escaping certain characters is an option in other environments/contexts.